# Redirect PHP notices and warnings from STDOUT to STDERR

Tags: php, bash, stdout, stderr, io-redirection

Is there a flag or a command available to redirect all PHP notices and warnings to STDERR on a single command you run on the command line?

I want to parse a JSON array from the command line, but sometimes I get notices and warnings from STDOUT which fail the JSON parsing.

The command looks like this:

```
rake collect
```

It's a rake task to collect some information about local websites.

Answer (score 3):

According to [configuration manual](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php), you need to set `display_errors` option to `stderr` in order to output warnings/errors to STDERR.

> **display_errors** string
>
> This determines whether errors should be printed to the screen as part of the output or if they should be hidden from the user.
>
> Value "stderr" sends the errors to stderr instead of stdout.

You can set this option in a few ways:

1) Globally (in `php.ini`)

```
display_errors = stderr
```

2) Locally in a script with `ini_set()`:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'stderr');
```

3) As a command line argument (without modifying any file)

```
php --define display_errors=stderr script.php
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a custom error handler.

```
set_error_handler (function ($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
        switch ($errno) {
              case E_USER_ERROR:
                   $ERROR = "CUSTOM ERROR";
                   break;
              //set cases for each error type
        }
        if($ERROR){
        $stderr = fopen('php://stderr', 'w');
        fwrite($stderr, $ERROR );
        fclose($stderr);
    }
});
```

Comment: But I'm using a Ruby `rake` task and the plan is to keep the server side code untouched.